# Preg_replace in foreach doesn't work properly

Tags: php, foreach, preg-replace

I have a problem with a PHP Code. This loop only executes the last regular expression in the file and when I change the sequence of expressions in the file and another expression becomes last, only this new last expression is executed.

```
foreach(file('general.txt') as $line) {
    $text = preg_replace("/" . $line . "/", "", $text);
}
```

The file general.txt contains lines of regular expressions, everything tested. But in this loop, it doesn't work anymore.

Do you maybe know why this is like this? I have tried a lot, but didn't figure out why...

Thank you

Simon

Comment: try to do $lines = file('general.txt'); and then then use $lines in foreach. Sometimes the foreach is weird about this stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to trim your lines as follows:

```
foreach(file('general.txt') as $line) {
    $text = preg_replace("/" . trim($line) . "/", "", $text);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `file()` function, you can use `fopen` and `stream_get_line` that removes the newline sequence. To do that, you must know the newline sequence used in your pattern file. Exemple with a Windows newline sequence:

```
$fh = fopen('patterns.txt', 'r');

if ($fh) {
    $nl = "\r\n";
    while ( false !== $line = stream_get_line($fh, 2048, $nl) ) {
        $str = preg_replace('/' . $line . '/', '', $str);
    }
}
```

A significant advantage over `trim`: you can use patterns that start or end with whitespaces.